# How to specify relative path to checkstyle config in root project in gradle 2.2+

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

I have the following project structure:

```
project
  checkstyle
    checkstyle.xml
  subproject1
    ...
  subproject2
    ...
  build.gradle
```

My configuration for checkstyle in the `build.gradle` is as follows:

```
allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
  checkstyle {
    configFile = 'checkstyle/checkstyle.xml' as File
  }
}
```

When I was using gradle 2.1, build worked OK. After upgrading to 2.2 or 2.2.1 the error occurs:

```
:subproject1:checkstyleMain FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':subproject1:checkstyleMain'.
> Unable to create a Checker: unable to find /home/my/project/subproject1/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml
```

Gradle is now looking for 'checkstyle/checkstyle.xml' in the subproject directory, which is not what I would expect.

I have found that [they mentioned this change in 2.2 release notes](https://gradle.org/docs/2.2/release-notes#configuring-code-quality-tasks/extensions-with-file-objects-representing-relative-paths). But they did not tell how to maintain old behavior of resolving that path. How to do this?

I tried using `project.file` but it does not work too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

in your snippet

```
allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
  checkstyle {
    configFile = 'checkstyle/checkstyle.xml' as File
  }
}
```

you configure the configfile per project to be relative from the subproject you're currently configuring. you can fix this by replacing

```
checkstyle {
    configFile = 'checkstyle/checkstyle.xml' as File
}
```

by

```
checkstyle {
    configFile = rootProject.file('checkstyle/checkstyle.xml')
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. But with previous version of gradle it was working well, why?

Comment: The change is mentioned in the release notes of 2.2: https://gradle.org/docs/2.2/release-notes#configuring-code-quality-tasks/extensions-with-file-objects-representing-relative-paths

Comment: I found that for pmd config works well just use `file('xxx)`, but checkstyle doesn't

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try replacing:

```
configFile = 'checkstyle/checkstyle.xml' as File
```

with:

```
configFile = ('checkstyle/checkstyle.xml' as File).absolutePath as File
```

and try if it works?

As mentioned [here](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.Checkstyle.html) `configFile` is replaced with [config](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.Checkstyle.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.Checkstyle:config). Can't try it but maybe:

```
config = 'checkstyle/checkstyle.xml' as File
```

will work?

Comment: But wait.. So what about: `('checkstyle/checkstyle.xml' as File).absolutePath`?

Comment: Unfortunately, Rene's solution is cleaner :-)

Comment: Ok, however  it doesn't answer the question directly. Rene's solution will work for both gradle 2.1 and 2.2. Your configuration stopped working with the new version of gradle and I explained why (hope so, can't check it) - I mean `config` vs `configFile`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler way to do this. Try the [`gradle-estilo-plugin`](https://github.com/anshulverma/gradle-estilo-plugin). It will take care of creating all the config files (checkstyle.xml, import-control.xml, suppressions.xml and header.txt). All you have to do is use the plugin in your gradle build file. If you need any custom rules, you can add them directly to your gradle task.

Here is what you'll need to get started:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'net.anshulverma.gradle:gradle-estilo-plugin:0.4.8'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'net.anshulverma.gradle.estilo'

estilo {
  source 'sun'
}
```

After this you can modify the checks, add suppressions, edit import control and add a header file directly from the `estilo { }` block. Details on how to do this and details including tips can be found in [README](https://github.com/anshulverma/gradle-estilo-plugin/blob/master/README.md).